# Search Result stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have 2 text boxes one is for resource and another one is for location.

As of now what I did is, I have created a stored procedure for displaying search results. My problem is while giving resource it's fetching the corresponding resource but also taking other resource that match with location

For example:

If I search for saloon in India it is displaying the results which is in the location( India ) and also display hospital, school etc.

Assume that:

```
textbox 1: Saloon
textbox 2: India
```

If i give like this my search results coming

**search result**

```
Resource : Naturals - India's No: 1
Location : India

Resource : Apollo Hospitals
Location : India

Resource : Sahyadri School
Location : India
```

***how to solve this ??***

Stored procedure is:

```
@SEARCH NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
@loc NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
as
select *
from tblBusinessCategory as b
    inner join tblUser as u on b.BusinessID=u.BusinessCategoryId
    inner join tblAddress as a on u.AddressId=a.AddressID

where a.City = @loc OR a.State = @loc
       OR b.BusinessName LIKE '%' + @SEARCH + '%'
Order By case when b.BusinessName = @SEARCH then 0 else 1 end
```

Comment: do you need to provide input data for both the text fields - Resource and Location?

Comment: Use `and` instead of `or` between the condition set of `resouces` and `locations`

Comment: Yes  Abhishek 2 text boxes must be filled

Comment: Lali can u explain it clearly ?

Comment: Looks like you should use: `(a.City = @loc OR a.State = @loc) AND b.BusinessName LIKE '%' + @SEARCH + '%'`

Comment: thanks kartic it works .. one more doubt .. if give resource in textbox withot givng location i need to dispaly all record corresponding to that resource .. how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this in to where:

```
where (@SEARCH IS NULL or (b.BusinessName LIKE '%' + @SEARCH + '%'))
  and (@loc IS NULL or (a.City = @loc OR a.State = @loc))
```

Simple exemple [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd256/1)

Comment: The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Double' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Double' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid.

Source Error: 


                using (SYTEntities context = new SYTEntities())
                {
                  cm = context.Database.SqlQuery<Search>("exec search_filter_sp @SEARCH,@loc", parameter).ToList();